# Finding the appropriate bounds of integration for this joint probability.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $f(x_1, x_2) =\begin{cases} 4x_1x_2, \ 0 < x_1 < 1, \  0 < x_2 < 1 \\ \\ 0, \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$,

be the pdf of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Find $P(X_1 = X_2)$.

I understand that conceptually $P(X_1 = X_2)$ would be the volume under the surface $f(x_1, x_2)$ and above the line segment $0 < x_1 = x_2 < 1$.

I would like to formulate that in terms of the definition of joint probability:

$$P[(X_1, X_2) \in A] = \int\int_A f_{{x_1},x_2}(x_1, x_2)dx_1dx_2.$$

But I'm not sure how the fact that $X_1 = X_2$ would affect the bounds of integration.

Comment: What does $f$ mean on the _right side_ of your $f(x_1,x_2)=fx_1x_2$? I understand what $f$ means on the left side but not in the right side.

Comment: Dilip - I apologize, that should be $f(x_1, x_2) = 4x_1x_2$. That was a typo.

Comment: Since $(X_1,X_2)$ has a density, $P(X_1=X_2)=0$.

Comment: I'm aware that the probability is in fact zero (We're finding the volume of a surface integrated over the line segment). My question is how to show this through a correct choice of integration bounds.

Comment: Here is one method that works: Set $A = \{X \geq Y\}, B = \{X \leq Y\}$ so that $A\cap B = \{X = Y\}$. Note that $A\cup B = \Omega$. You should be able to set integral limits straightforwardly to calculate $P(A)=P(B)=\frac 12$ and so we have that $$P(\{X=Y\} = P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B) = \frac 12+\frac 12 - 1 = 0.$$